# how sizeof empty enum is 4 in C++?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, enums

Consider following program (See live demo [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/sZXb5EVKqRjgYZCD))

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    enum days{}d;
    std::cout<<sizeof(d);
}
```

It prints 4 as an output on my local machine when compiling using g++ 4.8.1. How it occupies 4 bytes here? On gcc 6.0 in the given link I used `-pedantic-option also but still it compiles fine.

Then why it isn't allowed in C? I tried following program in gcc 4.8.1. (See live demo [here](http://ideone.com/pkSxOG) )

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    enum days{}d;
    printf("sizeof enum is %u",sizeof(d));
}
```

Compiler gives following errors:

```
4   12  [Error] expected identifier before '}' token

5   36  [Error] 'd' undeclared (first use in this function)

5   36  [Note] each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
```

Is it allowed to have empty enum in C++ but not in C?

Comment: C++ is not an extension of C, although many times it is confused to be. There's obviously a very wide common ground, but these are separate languages with separate rules.

Comment: gcc wont except this . C++ it is vald according to standard

Answer (score 11, accepted):

C++ is not C. For C++, from [dcl.enum]:

> For an enumeration whose underlying type is not fixed, the underlying type is an integral type that can
>   represent all the enumerator values defined in the enumeration. [...] It is implementation-defined which integral type is used
>   as the underlying type except that the underlying type shall not be larger than `int` unless the value of an
>   enumerator cannot fit in an `int` or `unsigned int`. If the *enumerator-list* is empty, the underlying type is **as if the enumeration had a single enumerator with value 0**.

So the underlying type of the enumerator (which determines its size) is as if it had a single 0 in it, though the actual type is implementation-defined. It could be 1 (`int8_t` certainly can hold 0), but definitely isn't larger than 4. In this case, you get 4, which is perfectly reasonable.

For C, the grammar simply requires having an enumerator.

Comment: How do do you know that the size of the enumeration is the size of the underlying type (assuming that's what "determines" is supposed to mean)? I'm not even sure anymore that the latter provides a lower bound.

Comment: @Columbo What else would it be?

Comment: That doesn't answer my question but raises another one. I was just hoping you found a quote I didn't find.

Comment: Your assumption is, of course, justified. If I don't find a DR or quote I'll potentially submit a DR myself later. Nevermind.

Comment: Can somebody translate this standardese into English: "For an enumeration whose underlying type is not fixed," What is the meaning of "underlying type is not fixed"?

Comment: @Columbo Yeah I don't see any specific wording about it, you're right. Just how there is an underlying type, and that it can be promoted to it, etc. But yeah, I guess a conforming implementation could stick 100 bytes of padding...

Answer (score 4):

As opposed to C, C++ does allow empty enumerations. [dcl.enum]/7:

> If the *enumerator-list* is empty, the underlying type is as if the
>   enumeration had a single enumerator with value `0`.

The underlying type (whose size is commonly also the enumerations size) is actually implementation-defined in your case, although most compilers will presumably choose `int` (and aren't allowed to chose anything larger here):

> It is implementation-defined which integral type is used as the
>   underlying type except that the underlying type shall not be larger
>   than `int` unless the value of an enumerator cannot fit in an `int` or
>   `unsigned int`.

---

C has the same requirements for the "underlying type" (although that exact notion doesn't exist in C), but its grammar does not allow for empty enumerations in the first place - §6.7.2.2/1:

> *enumerator-list*:
>       *enumerator* 
>      *enumerator-list* , *enumerator*

Answer (score 2):

You are right. You cannot have an empty enumerator list in C. But you can have it in C++. See http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/enum and http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/enum

Answer (score 1):

In C++ the size is 4 bytes because your compiler chose `int` as the underlying integer type for the enum. Apparently `sizeof(int)` is 4 on your platform. It is very popular in the compiler world to default to `int` for enum representation (unless a larger type is required).

As for why it isn't allowed in C... Well, it isn't allowed in C because it isn't allowed in C. C is a completely different language with its own syntactic rules.

Answer (score 1):

The [C11 standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf) requires at least one enumerator in an enum declaration (section 6.7.2.2), the salient parts copied below:

*enum-specifier*:
 **enum** *identifier<sub>opt</sub>* **{** *enumerator-list* **}**
 **enum** *identifier<sub>opt</sub>* **{** *enumerator-list* **}**
 **enum** *identifier*

*enumerator-list*:
 *enumerator*
 *enumerator-list***,** *enumerator*

Sorry for the somewhat wonky formatting, I tried to recreate the passage from the (proposed) standard as close as I could.